# Using .off() with emberjs' willDestroyElement()

Tags: jquery, ember.js

thanks in advance for looking at this.

Essentially, I'm calling didInsertElement() and binding an event to DOM `$(document).on(...)`

I'm trying to be a courteous developer and call `$(document).off(...)` by using willDestroyElement.

However, as I may have multiple things bound to `$(document)` i need to specify which function to remove. When I do this, jQuery hijacks Ember's `this` with it's own `HTMLElement`

**JsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/brennan/H65Ax/

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I'm curious why you are doing the whole `$(document).on(...)` `$(document).off(...)` in the first place? What is the final purpose of this?

Comment: Hey @pangratz I believe it was for closing dropdowns on a click to anything outside of the dropdown itself. 

I now use this same method for adding drag and drop file-upload for certain views.

Of course, I would love to know if i'm doing this in a weird way and if there are better options. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code like this:

```
didInsertElement: function(){
    var self = this;
    //storing `click` handler on new property `addedListener`
    $(document).off('click', self.addedListener = function(){
        self.set('isActive', false);
    });
},
willDestroyElement: function(){
    var self = this;
    $(document).off('click', self.addedListener);
},
```